# Release a listener / observer in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, listener, observer-pattern

I'm not sure when it's the right moment to RELEASE a listener object.

I have a object A that uses NSURLConnection's initWithRequest method to retrieve some URL.
initWithRequest requires a delegate to listen after the events of dataReceived...
So object A creates an object B and passes it as a delegate for initWithRequest method.

When the data is retrieved from the network a method of object B is called.
After object B has completed its work who has the responsability to release object B?!?

TO SUMMARIZE:

object A creates object B and make it listener for some event.
The event happens and object B makes its job.
After object B has done its job who has the responsability to release it?!?

PLEASE NOTE
There are many questions and answers on how to remove Observers in Objective-C.
Anyway all of them I found they assumed you are using the KVO pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried having object B release itself in the 'done receiving data' method?  That would seem to be the end of its useful life.  Or, you could maintain a reference to it in object A, and then release it in object A's dealloc method.

Comment: Yes the actually the method 'done receiving data' is the last moment when object B is used so it would be perfect to release it after that!

So an object can release itself?!?! I had thought about that but I thought it would cause an error!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [NSURLConnection Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The connection retains delegate. It
>   releases delegate when the connection
>   finishes loading, fails, or is
>   canceled.

NSURLConnection is an exception in this regard - most objects do not retain their delegates.

So, in this case, object A should retain object B if **A** wants to keep using B, in which case it should release it when done; NSURLConnection will take care of its own use of B.

Comment: The sentence from the reference you quoted helps a lot!! THANKS!!

So object A doesn't need to re-use connection and object B.
They are used only once to retrieve some data.

In this way a solution could be to release the connection object in the end of the method
(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 

when the connection is release it will cause also the object B to be automatically release since the connection object is the only wants that retains it!

Does this make sense?!